# Delayed variable expansion inside a substring operation

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, delayedvariableexpansion

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET str=123456789abcdefgh

FOR /l %%x IN (1, 1, 10) DO (

    SET /a intLength=10-%%x

    SET result=!str:~-%%x!
    ECHO "Works as intended: " !result!

    SET result=!str:~-intLength!
    ECHO "Does NOT work as intended: " !result!
)

endlocal
```

Comment: The complete rules for this type of managements are described at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990); you just need to change "array element" by "substring" in that description...

Answer (score 3):

You're using the literal string `intLength` instead of the `%intLength%` variable.

Since you're initializing a variable inside of a for loop, you're going to have to use the `!intLength!` variation of this variable name. Unfortunately, since you're already using exclamation points to get the substring from `str`, you can't also use them in that line to get the value of `intLength`, since you'd then essentially have a variable `!str:~!`, an unrelated string that batch *really* isn't going to like, and a `!!`.

You can get around this by running `!intLength!` through another for loop and using the `%%var` variable instead, since you've already shown that that works.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set str=123456789abcdefgh

for /l %%x in (1, 1, 10) DO (

    set /a intLength=10-%%x

    SET result=!str:~-%%x!
    echo Works as intended: !result!

    for /f %%A in ("!intLength!") do SET result=!str:~-%%A!
    echo Now works as intended: !result!
    echo.
)

endlocal
```